# Put option black scholes model

Tags: stochastic-analysis, monte-carlo

I have the following problem with a put option in a black scholes setting.

Consider a put option with time to maturity $T = 1$ and the underlying return $R$ following the log-normal model with volatility $σ\sqrt{T}$,
and assume that the risk-free return is $r = 0.04$.
First, I assume that $r_g = 0.06$ and $σ_1 = 0.25$.

I want to compute value of this option using the Black-Scholes formula. However, I can't figure out what to do?

When turning to Monte Carlo, I let $σ_1$ vary between $0.25, 0.3, 0.35$. I now want to recompute the value of this option using Monte Carlo method and compare them.

Assume now that $σ_1 = 0.25$ and that there is another asset
with $σ_2 = 0.35$ and that the two assets are correlated with correlation coefficient $ρ = −0.9$ and weights $w1, w2 = 0.5$.

I want to calculate the premium of the put option.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The appropriate place for this question is on https://quant.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The formula for computing the Black and Scholes price at time $t$ for a put with  maturity $T$, strike price $K$ and assuming a lognormal underlying asset following

$$
dS_t = \mu S_tdt + \sigma S_tdW_t
$$

is

$$
p_t = Ke^{r(T-t)}N(-d_2)-S_tN(-d_1),
$$

with

- $$N(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du$$
- $$d_1=\frac{\ln(\frac{S_t}{K})+(r+\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(T-t)}{\sigma \sqrt{T-t}}$$
- $$d_2=\frac{\ln(\frac{S_t}{K})+(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(T-t)}{\sigma \sqrt{T-t}}$$